# Configuration ELK + log4j

Tags: elasticsearch, log4j, logstash, jboss-4.0.x

I installed ELK on a ubuntu server 14.04. And now I wanted to send to this all my jboss sever logs (using log4j).

logstash configuration : 
input conf file :

```
input {
    log4j {
        type => "log4j"
        port => 5000
    }
}
```

filter conf file :

```
filter {
    if [type] == "log4j" {
        grok {
            match => {"message" => MY_GROK_PARSE}
        }
    }
}
```

and the output file :

```
output {
    elasticsearch {
        embedded => true
    }
}
```

And to finish the log4j appender:

```xml
<appender name="LOGSTASH" class="org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender"> 
    <param name="Port" value="5000"/>
    <param name="RemoteHost" value="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"/> <!-- There is a real adress here ;-) -->
    <param name="ReconnectionDelay" value="50000"/> 
    <param name="LocationInfo" value="true"/> 
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>
```

But nothing happens with this configuration. So I don't know what I misunderstand.
My other appenders (console and local file) work fine.
The elasticsearch log show any information/activity.

**Edit :** 
More about my jboss-log4j.xml:

```xml
<appender name="Async" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
    <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH" />
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="Async" />
</root>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that Logstash actually receives anything (you can check with a TCP traffic sniffer)? What if you replace the `elasticsearch` output with a simple `stdout` output to reduce the number of moving parts?

Comment: I did what you said. So for the TCP traffic I used 'sniffit' on port 5000 and this show nothing... (Is it ok using sniffit?)
I change the output and nothing happens too.

Comment: Okay, that indicates that there's something wrong with the Log4j configuration. How are you referencing the LOGSTASH appender in your logger configuration?

Comment: Yes, I add a part of log4j xml in my post to show you.
I already shutdown the firewall to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's an old post, but someone may find it useful - log4j SocketAppender can't use layout, see [docs for SocketAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html)

> SocketAppenders do not use a layout. They ship a serialized LoggingEvent object to the server side.

You also don't need additional filter in logstash configuration. Logstash log4j plugin minimal configuration is sufficient

```
input {
   log4j {
      data_timeout => 5
      host => "0.0.0.0"
      mode => "server"
      port => 4560
      debug => true
      type => "log4j"
   }
   ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send it directly to Elastic in this case. No reasons to go through LogStash first. You can easily use a filter to filter out messages you're not interested in.

I've written this appender here [Log4J2 Elastic REST Appender](https://github.com/magrossi/es-log4j2-appender) if you want to use it. It has the ability to buffer log events based on time and/or number of events before sending it to Elastic (using the _bulk API so that it sends it all in one go).
It has been published to Maven Central so it's pretty straight forward.